# How to set onChildAdded called when an child is added

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;
List<ListData> list;
RecyclerView recyclerview;
TextView badge;
String name, message, nameCaps;
int id, user_id;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle b) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, group, false);
    recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
    badge = view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("message");
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
            name = userdetails.getName();
            message = userdetails.getMessage();
            id = userdetails.getId();
            user_id = userdetails.getUser_id();
            nameCaps = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
            if (databaseHelper.checkUserID(user_id)) {
                databaseHelper.updateMsg(nameCaps, message, user_id);
            } else {
                databaseHelper.insertData(nameCaps, message, id, user_id);
            }
            list = databaseHelper.getData();
            RecyclerViewAdapter recycler = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
            name = userdetails.getName();
            message = userdetails.getMessage();
            id = userdetails.getId();
            nameCaps = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
            databaseHelper.updateData(nameCaps, message, id);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
            id = userdetails.getId();
            databaseHelper.deleteData(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

This is my code. When a child is added i saved it in `sqlite` database and fetch the data from database and load into `recyclerview` but `onChildAdded()` method calls on every time i open the app.How to set when i added a child then `onChildAdded()` calls otherwise it don't call `onChildAdded()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such way to find, because it always return you with all relevant data that are present on `Firebase`. There is no solution to restrict it as per my research and knowledge.

**There is a way to do that:**

For me the logic was is to have value -"status" for example- which needs to be validated before deciding whether it is really new or was an old record then I set the "status" to a different value so I don't get it next time:

```
@Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

                String Id = (String) dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue();
                String status = (String) dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue();

                if (Id != null && Id.equals(storedId) && status != null && status.equals("created")) {
                    Log.d("INCOMING_REQUEST", "This is for you!");
                    sessionsRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("status").setValue("received");
                }

            }


    }
```

Thanks and let me know if need more !!